# Background color is showing blue for some time when google map satellite view loading

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented google map and put default view as Satellite. But when page is loading background is showing blue before showing map. Its working fine when put map view default. I have checked with `backgroundColor: 'none'` in map option. But its not working.

I am using code like:

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(center_lat,center_long),
        zoom: 18,           
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions:
        {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID],
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT             
        },          
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions:
        {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        backgroundColor: 'none'
    });
```

Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: I don't think its blue background, It's sea. Your application might be sending different latitude and longitude at first, and then the actual one.

Comment: @Prajwal, thanks for reply. I have checked for center lat long in map option. e.g.  (30.704649, 76.717873) this latitude and longitude put in "center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.704649,76.717873)". But getting same issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  [I don't see anything like your picture if I put the posted code in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/LnL4ggop/) (but maybe your computer or network connection is slower than mine).

Comment: [with the coordinates in your comment](http://jsfiddle.net/LnL4ggop/1/)

Comment: I have check with static locations and it working fine but when i put dynamic value it is taking some time to fetch location information, so it is showing blue background before loading map. Can anyone suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was defining map variable before getting location details. I found a solution for this issue. define map variable after calling url for get location details. For example:

```
    $.getJSON('googlescript.php', function(items)
    {
        var center_lat = '30.704649';
        var center_long = '76.717873';

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(center_lat,center_long),
            zoom: 18,           
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions:
            {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID],
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT             
            },          
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions:
            {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            backgroundColor: 'gray'
        });

        var routePoints = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {                    
          (function(item) {                     
                addMarker(item.lat,item.long);
            })(items[i]);
            routePoints.push(new     google.maps.LatLng(items[i].lat,items[i].long));
            var route= new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: routePoints,
                        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                        strokeOpacity: .9,
                        strokeWeight: 3,
                        geodesic: true,
                        icons: [{
                            icon: {path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW},
                            offset: '0',
                            repeat: '100px'
                        }
                        ]
            });
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(center_lat,center_long));
        map.setZoom(18); 
        route.setMap(map);
        map.setTilt(0);         
        }

    });
    center = bounds.getCenter();
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```